# Command substitution when it involves environment path

Tags: bash

I run this command to list my android emulators:

```
emulator -list-avds
```

The output is:

```
Pixel_2_API_28
```

Now I can run the emulator using this command:

```
emulator -avd Pixel_2_API_28
```

Which works just fine. But I want to make an alias for this so that I can run the first found emulator with just one word.

```
emulator -avd "$(emulator -list-avds)"
```

But it errors: `PANIC: Cannot find AVD system path. Please define ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`. But the path is already defined, as you saw, the command when run without command substitution, executes just fine.

So I googled a lot and tried a lot of things to get this working. I tried combinations of `eval` and choosing the first row with `awk 'NR==1{print $1}'` and tried putting double quotes and single quotes and escaping the double quotes `\"` but nothing worked.

I tried storing the command in a variable and inspecting it:

```
a="$(emulator -list-avds)" ; declare -p a
```

And the variable looks weird to me:

```
"eclare -- a="Pixel_2_API_28
```

[image: output]

Maybe this is why it's not working. I have no idea what to google now and how to take this any further, I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: `emulator` outputs a string with DOS line endings. Try `emulator -avd "$(emulator -list-avds | tr -d '\r')"`.

Comment: Thanks very much, it works now, if you'd have the time to write an answer, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of `emulator` includes a DOS line ending (carriage-return/linefeed pair). The command substitution only strips the trailing linefeed, leaving the carriage return as part of the string passed as an argument to the next call.

To strip it, you can use `tr`:

```
emulator -avd "$(emulator -list-avds | tr -d '\r')"
```